# Optimizing a postgres request with arithmetical operators

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple request like this, on a very large table :

```
(select "table_a"."id",
        "table_a"."b_id",
        "table_a"."timestamp"
 from "table_a"
          left outer join "table_b"
                          on "table_b"."b_id" = "table_a"."b_id"
 where ((cast("table_b"."total" ->> 'bar' as int) - coalesce(
         (cast("table_b"."ok" ->> 'bar' as int) +
          cast("table_b"."ko" ->> 'bar' as int)), 0)) > 0 and coalesce(
              (cast("table_b"."ok" ->> 'bar' as int) +
               cast("table_b"."ko" ->> 'bar' as int)),
              0) > 0)
 order by "table_a"."timestamp" desc fetch next 25 rows only)
```

Problem is it takes quite some time :

```
Limit  (cost=0.84..160.44 rows=25 width=41) (actual time=2267.067..2267.069 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..124849.43 rows=19557 width=41) (actual time=2267.065..2267.066 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using table_a_timestamp_index on table_a  (cost=0.42..10523.32 rows=188976 width=33) (actual time=0.011..57.550 rows=188976 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using table_b_b_id_key on table_b  (cost=0.42..0.60 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=188976)
              Index Cond: ((b_id)::text = (table_a.b_id)::text)
"              Filter: ((COALESCE((((ok ->> 'bar'::text))::integer + ((ko ->> 'bar'::text))::integer), 0) > 0) AND ((((total ->> 'bar'::text))::integer - COALESCE((((ok ->> 'bar'::text))::integer + ((ko ->> 'bar'::text))::integer), 0)) > 0))"
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.411 ms
Execution Time: 2267.135 ms
```

I tried adding indexes :

```
create index table_b_bar_total ON "table_b" using BTREE (coalesce(
                                                            (cast("table_b"."ok" ->> 'bar' as int) +
                                                             cast("table_b"."ko" ->> 'bar' as int)),
                                                            0));

create index table_b_bar_remaining ON "table_b" using BTREE
    ((cast("table_b"."total" ->> 'bar' as int) - coalesce(
            (cast("table_b"."ok" ->> 'bar' as int) +
             cast("table_b"."ko" ->> 'bar' as int)), 0)));
```

But it doesn't change anything . How can I make this request run faster ?

Comment: I would suggest storing column for your filter value and creating index on that instead parser JSON

Comment: @D-Shih the issue I have is that the keys on my json are dynamic, and thus the where statement itself is generated at runtime. But I do have knowledge on how the statement later, so I am able to generate appropriate indexes. Idk if that makes sense. Do you think that's the underlying issue?

Comment: If you run the WHERE clause against just table b, how many rows does it expect?  How many does it find?

Comment: After building those expression indexes, did you ANALYZE the table?

Comment: Is the > comparator always 0, or will it change from execution to execution?

Comment: @jjanes That's interesting, but without the join clause, running only `select * from table b where ...` it does uses my indexes and is thus much faster. It has 176 000 rows and found 0 results. Analyzing the table did work wonderfully though !! Now it takes only 0.472ms and uses my indexes. !! Thanks a lot ! could you post it as an answer ? (btw it's always 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary column indexes don't have their own statistics, as the table's statistics are sufficient for the indexed to be assessed for planning.  But expressional indexes have their own statistics collected (on the expression results) whenever the table is analyzed.  But a problem is that creating an expressional index does not trigger an autoanalyze to be run on the table, so those needed stats can stay uncollected for a long time. So it is a good idea to manually run ANALYZE after creating an expressional index.

Since your expressions are always compared to zero, it might be better to create one index on the larger expression (including the >0 comparisons and the ANDing of them as part of the indexed expression), rather than two indexes which need to be bitmap-ANDed.  Since that expression is a boolean, it might be tempting to create a partial index with it, but I think that that would be a mistake.  Unlike expressional indexes, partial indexes do not have statistics collected, and so do not help inform the planner on how many rows will be found.